# How to install Flow (code suggestions) for React Native in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint, flowtype

I'm struggling in setting up flow on my VScode for react native, it seems hard to find a guide for a proper way to install it, need help please!

Comment: https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode

Comment: See this article:

https://hackernoon.com/configure-eslint-prettier-and-flow-in-vs-code-for-react-development-c9d95db07213

Comment: Thanks for the respond, is there any guide for Atom btw? appreciated for the tips